# classic asp cdo smtpserver send email timeout

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic

I am doing some testing on my local visual studio 2005 environment development server with classic asp.  The development link has a format like `http://localhost/.....`  The code works on a test server, but does not work in my local environment.  After I hit the submit button to send the email, the browser says "Waiting for localhost" for a little while and then gives me the following error.

Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0113'

Script timed out

The maximum amount of time for a script to execute was exceeded. You can change this limit by specifying a new value for the property Server.ScriptTimeout or by changing the value in the IIS administration tools.

UPDATE with the following code:

```
 Dim cdoConfig, sch
    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 
    sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"     
    With cdoConfig.Fields
         .Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 ' cdoSendUsingPort 
        .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "(smtpserver inserted here)"
        .Update 
    End With        
    Set objCDO = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set objCDO.Configuration = cdoConfig
```

Comment: We need some code here! Check on what line the error occurs and add this to your question. Maybe the page can't find your (local) smtpserver?

Comment: how do I find the line where the error occurs?

Comment: You can try and debug 'the old way': Set some Response.Write "1", Response.Write "2" etc. somewhere in your code and run it. Your page will count up until the time out occurs.

Comment: You'll need to have an SMTP server installed it's likely your code is timing out trying to send the `cdo.message`.

Comment: The other possibility is you have a configured SMTP server but a software firewall may be blocking communication to from your localhost, which fits with a script timeout.

Comment: The smtp server is able to be used to send email with my ASP.NET applications.  I'm not sure why this same smtp server is not able to send email for the classic asp application.